# Chart.js How to align x-ticks?

Tags: javascript, plot, chart.js

I have a number of points randomly distributed by time x-axis, and I'd like to draw ticks only at times like XX:00, keeping the possibility of showing individual tooltips for every point. Is it possible?

Sample code as soon as it required..
https://codepen.io/zzmaster/pen/YYmMmX

```
var data = {
    labels: ["2012-02-02 12:03:11", "2012-02-02 12:12:11", "2012-02-02 13:10:11", "2012-02-02 14:22:11"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            type: 'line',
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81]
        },
    ]
};

var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                displayFormats: {
                    'hour': 'HH:mm'
                },
            },
            ticks:{
                source: 'labels',
                maxTicksLimit: 20,
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Loading'
            },
        }],
    },

};;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Comment: please share your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub user etimberg answered this:

> removing source: 'labels' and setting unitStepSize: 0.5 achieves what you're looking for. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrQjXr

```
var data = {
    labels: ["2012-02-02 12:03:11", "2012-02-02 12:12:11", "2012-02-02 13:10:11", "2012-02-02 14:22:11"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            type: 'line',
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81]
        },
    ]
};

var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                unitStepSize: 0.5,
                displayFormats: {
                    'hour': 'HH:mm'
                },
            },
            ticks:{
                maxTicksLimit: 20,
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Loading'
            },
        }],
    },

};;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    options: options,
    data: data
})
```